# What is the algorithm used in System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider class in c#

Tags: .net, algorithm, c#-4.0, cryptography, cryptographic-hash-function

May be this is a silly question but it is sort of important as i am in the middle of a technical audit and a knowledge based  question.

I am looking at the C# 4.0 (which uses .net framework 4.0) code and wondering what algorithm is used in Microsoft's System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider class GetBytes method implementation.

The strength could be the number of byte buffer supplied but i am confused and could not locate whether the RNGCryptoServiceProvider uses a specific well known Algorithm or proprietary Microsoft.

I presume question is straight forward and I am pretty looking at an answer that tells the name of the documented algorithm or information that whether or not its proprietary Microsoft one.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by algorithm. The implementation uses a number of soft entropy sources from the OS to supply random numbers.

Comment: Name of Algorithm if it is publicly documented one(or something well known like skipjack blowfish etc) or an encryption standard.If it is proprietary then it may not have a name yet at least in the public domain.

Comment: There is no specific encryption algorithm associated with the method you're asking about. It could be used to generate key material for any of those algorithms.

Comment: So you are saying the steps ( or algorithm in other words) to create a random number is not available in public domain making Microsoft's proprietary.

Comment: Well, yes. But I think calling it an algorithm is misleading. The OS takes timing information from different sources and cryptographically mixes all of that into a pool. When you call GetBytes, that pool is used to provide strong random values. That being said, I do not believe Microsoft has ever published the details of the sources or hashing algorithms involved (I would be astounded if the hashing wasn't simply SHA or something similar).

Comment: I'm wrong - there is a fair amount of detail available here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom

Comment: Yep, it's just using the underlying Windows RNG. So the algorithm also depends on the Windows implementation underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Here is information detailing the approach used in CryptGenRandom.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom